# Manage Order view For Multy Store views

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento order view management from Multy Stores.

Hi I have one dought.

My dought is When view orders in the admin back end - Remove pricing if orders are from catalog in the view orders section. Display pricing if order received from shop site.

Here Catalog is one store view and shop is another store vie.